# Three way interaction GAM model with 2 categorical variables as well as random term

Tags: r, syntax, statistics, gam

I am trying to write a GAM model in the package 'mgcv' in R that will have a three way interaction with 2 categorical variables and one continuous variable, and also include a categorical random variable.
As an example, lets say that x1 is a categorical variable, x2 is a second categorical variable, x3 is continuous, and x4 is a categorical random variable. x1, x2 and x4 are converted to factors, and x3 is numerical.
I would like to examine the three way interaction between x1, x2 and s(x3), but am not sure the best way to program the model. I realize you could use 'te' and 'ti' basis terms but not sure of the correct approach.
Based on other posts, I see that you can use glm syntax for parts of the model, so for example:

gam(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1:x2 + s(x3))

should give the interaction of the two categorical variables plus the continuous variable. Is it as simple as just adding the random terms to the model as well?
Any advice would be muchly appreciated.

I have tried the following syntax to examine the main effects:

y ~ x1 + x2 + s(x3) + s(x4, bs='re') + s(x3,x4, bs='re')

However, this only includes the main effects of x1, x2, and s(x3). If you use the "by" syntax in mgcv, you can get two factor interactions by doing:

y ~ x1 + x2 + s(x3, by='x1') + s(x4, bs='re') + s(x3,x4, bs='re'), and
y ~ x1 + x2 + s(x3, by='x2') + s(x4, bs='re') + s(x3,x4, bs='re').

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem.  I think I can write the model as follows to get what I am looking for:   y~ x1 * x2 + s(x3, by=interaction(x1,x2)) + s(x4, bs='re') + s(x3,x4, bs='re'). I ran this model and it does give the three way interactions of x1,x2 and x3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a three-way interaction for `f1`, `f2`, and `x3` (where I have changed the `x` to `f` for the categorical variables to make it easier to track), then you can do that in a few ways, depending on how you want to decompose the effects.

Your model in your comment is close — I really don't understand why you included a random slope for `x3` by `f4` as you don't mention that in your question, or why this should be a random linear effect when you are assuming the fixed effects of `x3` are smooth? — but `interaction()` is the right idea here. What an interaction between a continuous variable and two categorical variables amounts to is separate smooths for each of the combinations of the levels of the two categorical variables in the training data.

What you'll want then is something like:

```r
library("dplyr")
my_data <- my_data |>
  mutate(f1f2 = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE))
# or with base R
# my_data <- my_data |>
#  transform(f1f2 = interaction(f1, f2, drop = TRUE))
y ~ f1 * f2 + s(x3, by = f1f2) + s(x4, bs = "re"), data = my_data
```

We want to be responsible for creating the interaction in the data first, rather than in the formula because when it comes to predicting from the model you can easily end up with the wrong levels on the factor if you let R handle the creation when forming the model frame from a supplied data set.

The main point with the above however is that you want `drop = TRUE` to ensure you have only levels for the observed combinations of the data. You could include `f1f2` in the parametric part of the model instead of `f1 * f2` as both will code for the group means for the combinations of `f1` and `f2`.

This formulation of the model may be inefficient however *if* most of the smooths for the combinations of levels of `f1` and `f2` are similar in shape. In that situation, it may be better to estimate a smooth that captures the common shape and then have group-level *difference* smooths that combine to give an estimate of the smooths effect on `y` of `x3` for each group. This is the kind of model we envisaged in our HGAM paper. However since we wrote that paper a newer, computationally-better-behaved way of specifying the model has been made available in {mgcv}, the `sz` basis. Hence I would consider decomposing your model into:

```r
y ~ s(x3) +                      # (1)
    s(x3, f1, bs = "sz") +       # (2)
    s(x3, f2, bs = "sz") +       # (3)
    s(x3, f1, f2, bs = "sz") +   # (4)
    s(x4, bs = "re"), # (5)
data = my_data
```

the numbered smooths now represent

1. the common smooth effect of `x3` on `y`
2. the *smooth* difference between (1) and the smooth effect of `x3` for each level of `f1`
3. the *smooth* difference between (1) and the smooth effect of `x3` for each level of `f2`
4. the *smooth* difference between (1) (and (2), and (3) because they are also in the model) and the smooth effect of `x3` for each level of the *combination* of levels of `f1` *and* `f2`
5. your random effect for `f4`

Because this model decomposes the smooth effects for `x3` at different levels of `f1` and `f2` into multiple smooths, those smooth effects for a given combination of levels of `f1` and `f2` are not present in the model as a single smooth you can plot, unlike the `by` model shown first. This means you will need to *predict* from the model to even see partial effects for each level, whereas in the `by` variant you can just plot the model with `plot()` or `gratia::draw()` say to see the estimate smooth effect of `x3` for each level.

The advantage of the `sz` formulation however is that it can be much more efficient. Let's assume that the smooth effect of `x3` on the response for each combination of levels of `f1` and `f2` uses about 8 degrees of freedom and that they all have roughly the same shape. The smooths for each level differ slightly in shape but they all share the same common shape, plus something that is unique to it's specific combination of levels of `f1` and `f2`. In such a situation, the `by` variant would spend roughly 8 degrees of freedom for **each** combination of levels of `f1` and `f2`. The `sz` variant would spend 8 degrees of freedom in total modelling the common shape and then the difference smooths might each use only 1 or a few degrees of freedom to model the smooth differences of each combination from this average smooth. Conversely, the `sz` variant will not be as efficient as the `by` if all the group-level smooths are grossly different in shape, because we will end up with more parameters and smoothing parameters to estimate in the former (`sz`).

Comment: Thanks Gavin, I really appreciate the help. In our study, the variable of most interest is x3 and how the response patterns change over x3, f1*x3, f2*x3 and f1f2*x3. x4 (in 'glm' terms) would be considered the 'random error' due to the replicates, however, it may be interesting to see the responses are to x3*x4 as well. Again, thank you for the help.